# How to set duration and easing properties for animate()

Tags: jquery

Below is my code. It works well but I dont' know how to add duration and easing it to it. And also I want to add a callback function.

```
    $(".pcs").animate({
        top:height/2-50,
        left:width/2-50,
        width:100,
        opacity:1,
    },{step: function(now,fx){
            $(".pcs").css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        }});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/. I'm not sure what other information you need.

Comment: I tried a lot of ways but no luck to add these properties with step:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Jquery animate function works like that:

```
element.animate( properties, options );
```

You can do:

```
$(".pcs").animate({
    top:height/2-50,
    left:width/2-50,
    width:100,
    opacity:1},{
        duration: 1000,/*A string or number determining how long the animation will run. (1000 = 1 second)*/
        easing: "linear",/*A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.*/
        step: function(now,fx){
            $(".pcs").css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Animation complete.
        }
    }
);
```

To find more details, you can take a look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

so you can use

```
            $(".pcs").animate({
                    top:height/2-50,
                    left:width/2-50,
                    width:100,
                    opacity:1,
                },{step: function(now,fx){
                        $(".pcs").css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
                    ,
                    duration: 200,// or any numeric value
                    easing: 'linear' // or any supported easing effect, for more easing effect you can used jquery ui
                    }});
```

Check about [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/easing/)  easing effects

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".pcs").animate({
      top:height/2-50,
      left:width/2-50,
      width:100,
      opacity:1,
   }, {
      step:function(now,fx){
         $(".pcs").css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
      },
      duration: /*int*/,
      easing: /*string*/,
      complete: /*function when animation is complete*/
   });
```